# How to merge two CSV files only on same column names

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

Imagine I have a dataframe like this:

```
First <- data.frame(name=rep(c("Clay","Garrett","Addison"),each=3),
                   test=rep(1:3, 3),
                   score=c(78, 87, 88, 93, 91, 99, 90, 97, 91))

     name test score
1    Clay    1    78
2    Clay    2    87
3    Clay    3    88
4 Garrett    1    93
5 Garrett    2    91
6 Garrett    3    99
7 Addison    1    90
8 Addison    2    97
9 Addison    3    91
```

And also:

```
Second <- data.frame(name=rep(c("Jim","Jordan"),each=3),
                    test =rep(1:3, 2),
                    color = c("red", "brown", "red", "red", "blue", "green"))
    name    test color
1    Jim      1   red   
2    Jim      2 brown   
3    Jim      3   red   
4 Jordan      1   red   
5 Jordan      2  blue   
6 Jordan      3 green
```

Now I want to attach Second dataframe to First dataframe so that I have:

```
     name test score
1    Clay    1    78
2    Clay    2    87
3    Clay    3    88
4 Garrett    1    93
5 Garrett    2    91
6 Garrett    3    99
7 Addison    1    90
8 Addison    2    97
9 Addison    3    91
10 Jim       1    NA
11 Jim       2    NA
12 Jim       3    NA
13 Jordan    1    NA
14 Jordan    2    NA
15 Jordan    3    NA
```

So basically like **LEFT JOIN** but column wise, so I only keep the columns from first dataframe and if the same column cannot be found in the second dataframe, I have NA for the values for that column

Comment: Please don't repost or leave irrelevant old content, just edit to the best presentation you can at edit time. (Deleted non-upvoted posts still count towards posting limits.) If "the above example didn't truly represent my dataset" then it doesn't belong here. But also code that initializes a table should be formatted as a table so it is readable. And be minimal. Like the rest of the [mre] it forms. Which should what you are able to do.  [mre] [ask] [Help] PS This is unclear about how output is a function of input. A "asically" doesn't make unclear text clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need `bind_rows` here i.e. bind the first dataset ('First') with the 'Second' with only `intersect` column names from both datasets

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(First, Second[intersect(names(First), names(Second))])
```

-output

```
      name test score
1     Clay    1    78
2     Clay    2    87
3     Clay    3    88
4  Garrett    1    93
5  Garrett    2    91
6  Garrett    3    99
7  Addison    1    90
8  Addison    2    97
9  Addison    3    91
10     Jim    1    NA
11     Jim    2    NA
12     Jim    3    NA
13  Jordan    1    NA
14  Jordan    2    NA
15  Jordan    3    NA
```

---

If the column types are different, we may need to make the columns same type or use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(First,  Second[intersect(names(First), 
      names(Second))]), fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank @akrun, what if the columns have different types? for example "test" columns i character in the first data frame but "numeric" in the second one.

Comment: @Roozbeh_you by changing the `First$score <- as.character(First$score)` the `bind_rows` is working though i.e. it converts the columns to character in the final output

Comment: Unfortunately, I just found that the type of 24 columns are different! My bad! my example didn't correctly represent what I have in my dataset. Thanks for your solution though

Comment: @Roozbeh_you do you get any errors with both the solutions?

Comment: The type issue is related to the source files itself.  i.e suppose one file column that is supposed to be numeric have an element 'x1.5' or `$1.5`, it is not numeric anymore whereas in the other files, you have `1.5` and that would be read as numeric

Comment: yes. I should have used my actual dataset here for a better demonstration. The example I showed above is not completely representing my actual dataset., I'll try changing the column type and see how it's gonna work.

Comment: ok, thanks.  Please update your post with `dput` of slice of your original data so that it is reproducible.